# How to send csv file as an attachment using python while taking care of leading zeros

Tags: python, csv

I want to send a email using CSV File as an attachment ,When I open the email I receive an attachment where we do not have a Leading Zero ,I want leading zero to appear in the attachment of CSV File using python ,Please suggest me a workaround .

Results file is the CSV File :
The sample data looks : 0763808075

But when I run the python script the email attachment the data looks like this : 763808075.

I want the leading zero to be added in the email attachment

```
with open ( resultsfile1 , "rb" ) as attached_file :
        part = MIMEApplication (
            attached_file.read() ,
            Name=resultsfile1
        )
    # After the file is closed
result= os.path.basename ('\filename.csv')
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={} '.format(str(result))
msg.attach ( part )
```

Comment: If you open the attachment in a text editor (**not** a spreadsheet), are the leading zeroes present?

Comment: Yes it is present ,But in csv or excel it is not present ,Hence I would need a solution which will help me ensure the leading zeros are present in the attachment when the user opens the file sent through gmail

Comment: Not using Excel is almost always the right solution. Your Python code is fine.

Comment: Why do you open the file as binary though? CSV is inherently a text format.

Comment: Is there a way to attach CSV file in a attachment keeping Leading zeros ,we need the phone number to be attached in the report ,and the Phone number starts from 0 ,and it is very important for us to send this ,Even after changing open file to Text the leading zeros issue is still open